# Remove dependency to Application class in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a xamarin app where I have a static property where its value is updated when the user browses through the different pages.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Under the ViewModel of each page, I have a go to Next Page Command which updates when the user click the next button.

```
public async void GoToNextAsync() 
{
   App.Status = "PageName"
}
```

However, this makes the VM impossible to run unit test due to its dependency on App class.

What is the best way to refactor the codes?

Comment: You can use the `Application.Current.MainPage` to get the current page!

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this is using the existing MainPage property to get the CurrentPage's name (Better than using any static property)

Now the good thing about the MainPage is that it is a Static property that maintains itself hence can be used anywhere in the Project where your `.NetStandard` is available

```
var pagename = Application.Current.MainPage.GetType().Name;
```

Comment: Yes, we can get the page name like this. However I am trying removing to references to App.Status because I have to open the Xamarin app to test everytime..

Comment: Yeah that is the reason I have given you this code you can use this to get the current page name `status` as per you literally anywhere you want so you do not need the Status property anymore anyway, am i making sense?